# Arreglo Bidimensional de Multiplicacion de Matrices con resultado en una tercera matriz JAVA

Tags: java, array, array-bidimensional

Buenas tardes esto me mandaron a resolver e hice lo siguiente pero me imprime la multiplicacion correctamente  pero me agrega una fila extra de ceros; además tambien me multiplica cuando la columna y fila no son iguales porfavor ayuda aun no entiendo bien arreglos.
Definir y crear tres arreglos bidimensionales de (m x n - m filas x n columnas) de igual tamaño
que representen matrices, llenar dos arreglos con números aleatorios y determinar la
multiplicación de las matrices y almacenar el resultado en el tercer arreglo e imprimir las
matrices originales y la matriz resultante de la multiplicación.

```
package ej17_bidimensionales;

public class EJ17_BIDIMENSIONALES {


    
    public static void MultiplicacionMatrices (int fila1, int columna1,int fila2, int columna2)
    {
      //LLENAR 
        
      int [][] Matriz1;
      Matriz1 = new int [fila1][columna1];
        
        System.out.println("MATRIZ 1");
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz1.length; i++) 
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < Matriz1[0].length; j++)
             {
                Matriz1[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100); 
             }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz1.length; i++) 
        {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < Matriz1[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Matriz1[i][j]+ "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        System.out.println("MATRIZ 2");
        
        int [][] Matriz2;
        Matriz2 = new int [fila2][columna2];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz2.length; i++) 
        {
             for (int j = 0; j < Matriz2[0].length; j++)
             {
               Matriz2[i][j] = (int)(Math.random()*100); 
             }
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz2.length; i++) 
        {
            
            for (int j = 0; j < Matriz2[0].length; j++) 
            {
                System.out.print(Matriz2[i][j]+ "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        
        //OPERACIONES
        
        int[][] producto = new int[Matriz2.length][Matriz2[0].length];
        
        
        // Necesitamos hacer esto por cada columna de la segunda matriz (B)
        for (int a = 0; a < Matriz2[0].length; a++) {
            // Dentro recorremos las filas de la primera (A)
            for (int i = 0; i < Matriz1.length; i++) {
                int suma = 0;
                // Y cada columna de la primera (A)
                for (int j = 0; j < Matriz1[0].length; j++) {
                    // Multiplicamos y sumamos resultado
                    suma += Matriz1[i][j] * Matriz2[j][a];
                }
                // Lo acomodamos dentro del producto
                producto[i][a] = suma;
            }
        }

        // Recorrer producto
        System.out.print("Imprimiendo producto\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < Matriz2.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matriz2[0].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%d ", producto[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    
        
    }    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      MultiplicacionMatrices(1,1,2,2);

    }
    
}
```

Comment: tu ejercicio dice claramente 3 matrices bidimensionales de igual tamaño, sim embargo en tu código la matriz1 la declaras de tamaño 1x1 y la matriz2 de tamaño 2x2

Comment: eso era para comprobar el codigo en caso de que escriban de diferente tamaño

Comment: como condicionaria el mismo tamaño para los tres entonces?

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de la multiplicación de matrices, un elemento de la fila de la primera matriz se multiplica por todas las columnas de la segunda matriz.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al pasar n filas m columnas como parámetro declaras los 3 arreglo bidimensionales con el mismo tamaño, lo demás es aplicación de la imagen

```
public static void multiplicacionMatrices (int n,int m){
     
      System.out.println("MATRIZ 1");  
      int [][] matriz1 = new int [n][m]; 
      //llenar(matriz1); 
      //imprimir(matriz1);
      System.out.println("MATRIZ 2");  
      int [][] matriz2=new int [n][m];
       
      //llenar(matriz2);
      //imprimir(matriz2);

      int[][] producto = new int[n][m];
      for(int i=0;i<producto.length;i++){    
         for(int j=0;j<producto[i].length;j++){    
            producto[i][j]=0;      
             for(int k=0;k<producto[0].length;k++){      
                producto[i][j]+=matriz1[i][k]*matriz2[k][j];      
                  }            
            }     
         }      
     //imprimir(producto);
 }
```

puedes comprobar los resultados [aqui](https://matrixcalc.org/es/#%7B%7B7,5,5%7D,%7B1,7,9%7D,%7B7,4,0%7D%7D*%7B%7B8,5,8%7D,%7B0,4,9%7D,%7B4,7,4%7D%7D)